# How to get <View ... > with code in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the height dynamically of a line defined by View in Xml to 1dp when a certain condition arises

```
  <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
```

How do i grab this View, so i can change its height dynamically?

For an ImageView i use

```
public ImageView theImage;

....
public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    theImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    **and then whatever condition**
}
```

but if do

```
public ImageView theImage;
public View theLine;

...

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        theImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        theLine = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.line);

        **and then whatever condition change the height to 1dp**

}
```

I get a gray (View) with **Casting 'itemView.findViewById(R.id.line)' to 'View' is redundant**

I presume (View) cannot be used in this way

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you dont need to cast it?! Remove the `(View)` from the line and see what happens.

Comment: Ok ill give that a go

Comment: @ iturki 10 -- thanks that worked

Comment: You are welcome. Will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast is redundant because findViewById always returns a View object. You can leave the (View) cast in as it will have no effect, but it's pointless in this case, so you can also get rid of it.

If you were looking up a TextView, the cast would be required. See the [casting objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) subsection for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to the definition of the `findViewById` method. The signature is as follows:

```
public View findViewById(int);
```

As you can see, the return type is `View`. You only need a cast (That's the `(View)findViewById(R.id.line)` thingy) when the return value of a method isn't the type you wanted. For example, if you want an `ImageView`, but the return value type is `View`, you need to do:

```
(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.image);
```

Casting takes the following form:

```
(Type1)value1
```

This would return a value of `Type1` but `value1`'s type must be compatible with `Type1` to do this. You can search Java Casting on google if you want more info.

Comment: Thanks i get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't cast the View because it is returned a View already. **Solution?** Try this:

```
theLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.line);
```

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` returns `View`

That's why it tells you that it is not needed to cast it to `View`, because you are casting a `View` object as `View`

While `ImageView` is a subclass of `View`, that is the case which you need casting.